# How do I set up a refspec that does the following?

Tags: git

This works to push my 'master' branch to a remote branch, "production"

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/production
```

However, how do I save the remote location so I can simply do `git push production master`? I don't want a production branch locally. It's development until I push it up. Then I just want to do

```
git merge production
```

On the server to grab the latest copy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can quite get what you want (with "what you want" being `git push production master`) here, but you can get something slightly simpler with two config entries:

```
git config remote.production.url ssh://...
git config remote.production.push master:production
```

after which:

```
git push production
```

will push to the specified URL (note: you can set `remote.production.pushurl` to make separate URLs for `production` for fetch and push, but that's probably not needed here).  Since there is no refspec after the remote, `git push` will consult `remote.production.push` to set one.  Since there *is* a `remote.production.push` it will then use that instead of any configured `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` (if those exist) or `remote.pushdefault` (if those do not exist).

The drawback here is that if you accidentally write:

```
git push production master
```

then `git push` will see that you specified a refspec and ignore `remote.production.push`.  The specified refspec is equivalent to (the full, longwinded version) `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`.

---

To avoid that last drawback, instead of fooling about with all of these things, you can simply configure an alias, e.g.:

```
git config alias.pushprod "push origin master:production"
```

after which:

```
git pushprod
```

is an even shorter way to "type in" the full command that already works.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
git push -u origin master:refs/heads/production
```

then Git will remember the upstream branch (the `-u` stands for "set upstream").

Comment: How did that work? `Branch master set up to track remote branch production from origin. Everything up-to-date`

Comment: The setting is stored in `.git/config`.

Comment: That's not what I wanted. The above snippet pushes the master branch to the remote branch production on origin. I don't want to mess with my master branch.

Comment: After setting the upstream, just do `git push` instead of `git push origin master`.

Comment: I don't want that to be my main upstream. It's just one server. I just want the "branch" pushable by something reasonable. I want the exact syntax in the question, if at all possible.

Comment: So do you actually want a remote called `production` that is possibly separate from `origin`?